# Linux SMB Client Failed to Connect to SMB Server Forcing AES-256?

Tags: fedora, encryption, smb, smbclient

I'm trying to connect to SMB share on my TrueNAS from my Fedora. It works well until I decided to enable encryption of SMB data. I put following in the service config on TrueNAS (global settings)

```
unix extensions = yes
server signing = required
client smb encrypt = required
server smb3 encryption algorithms = -AES-128-GCM -AES-128-CCM
```

and following in the particular SMB share (per-share settings)

```
server smb encrypt = required
```

Then, I tried to mount the SMB share by

```bash
sudo mount -t smb3 -o cred=<my_cred_file>,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS /mnt/NAS
```

and, boom, `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

In `dmesg`, it says

```
[112496.066462] CIFS: Attempting to mount //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS
[112496.085283] CIFS: VFS: sign fail cmd 0x3 message id 0x3
[112496.085287] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> SMB signature verification returned error = -13
[112496.085290] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> failed to connect to IPC (rc=-13)
[112496.085294] CIFS: VFS: session 00000000639775cf has no tcon available for a dfs referral request
[112496.085480] CIFS: VFS: sign fail cmd 0x3 message id 0x4
[112496.085481] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> SMB signature verification returned error = -13
[112496.085684] CIFS: VFS: sign fail cmd 0x2 message id 0x5
[112496.085687] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> SMB signature verification returned error = -13
[112496.085690] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> __cifs_put_smb_ses: Session Logoff failure rc=-13
[112496.085700] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

If I remove the line forcing AES-256 (disallowing AES-128):

```
server smb3 encryption algorithms = -AES-128-GCM -AES-128-CCM
```

the `mount` command will work fine.

However, even if I keep the forcing AES-256 config, I can still connect to my SMB share from Finder on macOS and iOS, and from Dolphin on KDE (I use fedora with KDE).

So, does `smbclient` in cli not support AES-256 encryption at all? Or can I turn something on and make the mount work totally fine?

Btw, `smbclient --version` gives `Version 4.19.4`.

---

Update: Following is the verbose output of `mount` as suggested by comment.

```bash
$ sudo mount -t smb3 --verbose -o cred=<my_cred_file>,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS /mnt/NAS
mount.smb3 kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.smb3(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.smb3) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

---

Update: Tried different `sec` options:

- `krb5`/`krb5i`:

  - `mount` verbose outputs:

    ```bash
    $ sudo mount -t smb3 --verbose -o cred=<my_cred_file>,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks,sec=<krb5/krb5i> //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS /mnt/NAS
    mount.smb3 kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,sec=<krb5/krb5i>,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
    mount.smb3 kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,sec=<krb5/krb5i>,uid=1000,cruid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
    mount error(126): Required key not available
    Refer to the mount.smb3(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.smb3) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
    ```
  - `dmesg` outputs:

    ```
    [190212.841620] CIFS: Attempting to mount //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS
    [190212.851741] CIFS: VFS: unknown or missing server auth type, use krb5
    [190212.861466] CIFS: VFS: Verify user has a krb5 ticket and keyutils is installed
    [190212.861472] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> Send error in SessSetup = -126
    [190212.861487] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
    ```
- `ntlm/ntlmi`:

  - `mount` verbose outputs:

    ```bash
    $ sudo mount -t smb3 --verbose -o cred=<my_cred_file>,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks,sec=<ntlm/ntlmi> //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS /mnt/NAS
    mount.smb3 kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
    mount error(22): Invalid argument
    Refer to the mount.smb3(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.smb3) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
    ```
  - `dmesg` outputs:

    ```
    [190683.752148] bad security option: <ntlm/ntlmi>

    [190683.752170] CIFS: VFS: bad security option: <ntlm/ntlmi>
    ```
- `ntlmv2`/`ntlmv2i`/`ntlmssp`/`ntlmsspi`: These four options makes no difference in `mount` verbose output or `dmesg` compared with not specifying any `sec` option.

---

Update: Tried `cifs` with specifying `vers` option:

- `vers=2.0`:

  - `mount` output:

    ```
    mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,vers=2.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
    mount error(13): Permission denied
    Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
    ```
  - `dmesg`:

    ```
    [281141.068174] CIFS: Attempting to mount //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS
    [281141.085261] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> smb2_calc_signature: Could not find session
    [281141.085286] CIFS: VFS: \\<TrueNAS IP> __cifs_put_smb_ses: Session Logoff failure rc=-2
    [281141.085298] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
    ```
- `vers=1.0`:

  - `mount` output:

    ```
    mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<TrueNAS IP>,unc=\\<TrueNAS IP>\NAS,mfsymlinks,vers=1.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<My Username>,pass=********
    mount error(95): Operation not supported
    Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
    ```

    I removed `mfsymlinks` (which is not supported in SMB1.0?) but the output is the same.
  - `demsg`:

    ```
    [281295.220579] Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers

    [281295.220601] CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
    [281295.220609] CIFS: Attempting to mount //<TrueNAS IP>/NAS
    [281295.231815] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
    ```

Comment: Add the `-vvv` switch to the `mount` command and add the output to the question. Do not post it in the comments.

Comment: @NasirRiley I think `-vvv` is the same as `--verbose`? Whatever, I updated my question.

Comment: If you add `sec=ntlmv2`, `sec=ntlmv2i`, `sec=ntlmssp`, or `sec=ntlmsspi` as in `cred=<my_cred_file>,sec=ntlm#,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks` what result do you get?

Comment: @NasirRiley As updated in my question, these four options makes no difference in `mount` verbose output or `dmesg` compared with not specifying any `sec` option.

Comment: You tried `ntlm` and `ntlmi` which are different. I knew that they would give that output which is why I didn't include them. Use the options that I specified and add the output to the question.

Comment: @NasirRiley The outputs of ntlmv2/ntlmv2i/ntlmssp/ntmlsspi are just the same as the output when I specifying no `sec` option. The `dmesg` is already included in the question before the first update and the verbose output of `mount` is already included in the first update.

Comment: The commands that you have don't include `v2` which is why I asked a second time but no matter. If you add `vers=2.0` or `vers=1.0` to the mount options, does it mount? Add the output to the question as usual.

Comment: @NasirRiley Replaced `smb3` with `cifs` so that I can specify a lower version, but both versions don't work.